# Inconsistent results using python read xml file

Tags: python, xml

I have two xml files and there are some common fields. I tried to read them but strangely, the result is always inconsistent when I change the order of the calls.
The first xml is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ms:record xmlns:ms="http://www.example.org/ns1">
    <ms:basic>
        <ms:name>zhangsan</ms:name>
        <ms:sex>male</ms:sex>
        <ms:age>30</ms:age>
    </ms:basic>
    <ms:group>Dev</ms:group>
    <ms:hobbies>
        <ms:hobby>TV</ms:hobby>
        <ms:hobby>Music</ms:hobby>
        <ms:hobby>Play</ms:hobby>
    </ms:hobbies>
</ms:record>
```

The second xml is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ms:record xmlns:ms="http://www.example.org/ns2">
<ms:name>zhangsan</ms:name>
<ms:group>Dev</ms:group>
    <ms:hobbies>
        <ms:hobby>TV</ms:hobby>
        <ms:hobby>Music</ms:hobby>
        <ms:hobby>Play</ms:hobby>
    </ms:hobbies>

    <ms:histories>
        <ms:history>
        <ms:start>2012</ms:start>
        <ms:job>SW Engineer</ms:job>
    </ms:history>
        <ms:history>
            <ms:start>2015</ms:start>
            <ms:job>Senior SW Engineer</ms:job>
        </ms:history>
    </ms:histories>
</ms:record>
```

The code logic is simple, read from xml file and return dict:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse, fromstring


def read_xml(target_dir):
    """
    read xml file
    """
    try:
        parser = parse(target_dir)
        return parser
    except Exception, ex:
        print ex


def read_xml1(upload):
    result = {}
    NAMESPACE1 = "http://www.example.org/ns1"
    parser = read_xml(upload)
    info_list = [
        ["name", ".//ms:name"],
        ["sex", ".//ms:sex"],
        ["age", ".//ms:age"],
        ["hobbies", "ms:hobbies//ms:hobby"],
        ["group", "ms:group"],
    ]
    function_map = {"hobbies": parser.findall}
    for info in info_list:
        key, value = info[0], info[1]
        try:
            parser_function = function_map.get(key, parser.find)
            ele = parser_function(value,
                                  {"ms": NAMESPACE1})
            if ele is not None:
                if type(ele) == list:
                    result[key] = [entry.text.strip() for entry in ele]
                else:
                    result[key] = ele.text.strip()
        except Exception, ex:
            print ex
    return result


def read_xml2(upload):
    result = {}
    NAMESPACE2 = "http://www.example.org/ns2"
    parser = read_xml(upload)
    history_sub = [
        ["start", "ms:start"],
        ["job", "ms:job"],
    ]
    info_list = [
        ["hobbies", "ms:hobbies//ms:hobby", None],
        ["name", "ms:name", None],
        ["histories", ".//ms:history", history_sub],
        ["group", "ms:group", None],
    ]

    function_map = {"hobbies": parser.findall,
                    "histories": parser.findall}
    for info in info_list:
        key, value, mapping = info[0], info[1], info[2]
        try:
            parser_function = function_map.get(key, parser.find)
            ele = parser_function(value,
                                  {"ms": NAMESPACE2})
            if ele is not None:
                if type(ele) == list:
                    if mapping:
                        sub_list = []
                        for entry in ele:
                            temp = {}
                            for sub_entry in mapping:
                                sub_key, sub_value = sub_entry[0], sub_entry[1]
                                sub_ele = entry.find(sub_value,
                                                     {"ms": NAMESPACE2})
                                temp[sub_key] = sub_ele.text.strip() if sub_ele is not None else ""
                            sub_list.append(temp)
                        result[key] = sub_list
                    else:
                        result[key] = [entry.text.strip() for entry in ele]
                else:
                    result[key] = ele.text.strip()
        except Exception, ex:
            print ex
    return result
```

When I call them one by one, the result is as expect

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print read_xml1(r"C:\11.xml")
```

The result is like below:

```
 {'age': '30', 'hobbies': ['TV', 'Music', 'Play'], 'group': 'Dev', 'name': 'zhangsan', 'sex': 'male'}
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print read_xml2(r"C:\22.xml")
```

The result is like below:

```
 {'histories': [{'start': '2012', 'job': 'SW Engineer'}, {'start': '2015', 'job': 'Senior SW Engineer'}], 'group': 'Dev', 'name': 'zhangsan', 'hobbies': ['TV', 'Music', 'Play']}
```

But when I call them together, the result is strange:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print read_xml1(r"C:\11.xml")
    print read_xml2(r"C:\22.xml")
```

The result seems some conflicts, the keys in 11.xml are not in 22.xml:

```
{'age': '30', 'hobbies': ['TV', 'Music', 'Play'], 'group': 'Dev', 'name': 'zhangsan', 'sex': 'male'}
{'histories': [{'start': '2012', 'job': 'SW Engineer'}, {'start': '2015', 'job': 'Senior SW Engineer'}], 'name': 'zhangsan', 'hobbies': []}
```

Then I tried to change the call order, the result is different:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print read_xml2(r"C:\22.xml")
    print read_xml1(r"C:\11.xml")
```

```
{'histories': [{'start': '2012', 'job': 'SW Engineer'}, {'start': '2015', 'job': 'Senior SW Engineer'}], 'group': 'Dev', 'name': 'zhangsan', 'hobbies': ['TV', 'Music', 'Play']}
{'age': '30', 'hobbies': [], 'name': 'zhangsan', 'sex': 'male'}
```

I don't know how to explain. It looks like some things are shared and rewritten.